# Determining the Class of a given Cellular Automata structure

Tags: automata-theory

Is it possible to write an algorithm that can determine the class of a given cellular automata structure ? (ie. Wolfram's 4 Classes)

Thank you

Ricky

Answer (score 9):

No. See

Culik, Karel, II; Yu, Sheng.
[Undecidability of CA classification schemes](http://www.complex-systems.com/pdf/02-2-2.pdf). 
*Complex Systems* 2 (1988), no. 2, 177–190.